# Pyspark - Dataproc - read SQL Server table using Kerberos(Windows Authentication enabled service account)

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, kerberos, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm able to run my pyspark program locally that fetches data from SQL Server instance (IaaS) using Kerberos authentication.

These are the steps

1. Created a Service Account
2. Added Service Account as a user in SQL Server database. Enabled Windows Authentication
3. Added [realms] in the `krb5.conf` file. Followed this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15#get-the-kerberos-key-distribution-center
4. Ran `kinit <service_account>@DOMAIN.COM"` command and entered password manually (note: I'm not able to generate the correct keytab file using the `ktutil` command, as the service account's password contains special characters. Hence couldn't pass the keytab file path to the `kinit` command)
5. Used Spark JDBC connector in my pyspark program to read from the source database. This is the connection string:

   ```
   connection_string = "jdbc:sqlserver://<host_name>:<port>;databaseName=<db_name>;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;disableStatementPooling=false"
   ```
6. I'm able to read the data by using the service account's Windows authentication in my local spark cluster.

Now, I'm not sure about what needs to be done to run the exact same script in a Dataproc cluster.

My questions are:

1. How do I setup the whole Kerberos configuration in the Dataproc cluster?
2. How should I handle the token refresh once the cluster is created?
3. Any code snippets/documentation to run my pyspark program on a Dataproc cluster will be helpful.

Comment: Does this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-google-dataproc/) help you to run the PySpark program on Dataproc cluster? To configure Kerberos in the Dataproc cluster, you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/security#gcloud-create-kerberos-cluster).